terra package "intersect" aborts R session, "aggregate" takes forever
I am using package terra to work with one SpatVector Object1 that is lon/lat WGS 84 and spans Central America from southern Mexico to Darien. The object has 2,892,488 geometries which delimit patches of forest. Before further processing I want to run the command "aggregate(Object1)", but it takes more than 48 hours to complete. I am working with R 4.3.0, RStudio 2024.09.1, and Windows 10 Pro with an Intel Core i7 processor and 32 Gigabytes of RAM. The shapefile corresponding to Object1 has about 867 MegaBytes. Does this look like a hardware limitation or should there be solutions for expediting the process without getting a more powerful computer?
I am ready to share links to the objects if anyone wants to try them.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please choose the problem you'd like to focus this Question upon, and [Edit] the Question to suit. Note that an 867MiB shapefile is a ridiculously complex layer, and might exceed the capability of any software to process.

Thank you. My apologies for asking a two-part question. The new version is more focused. As for the complexity of the layer being ridiculous. Perhaps it is, but this is the external source of information that I have to work with, even if I agree with your subjective judgment of its quality. That is why I request that the narrowed question be reviewed.

Shapefile isn't the best format for this sort of thing, and converting all those parts into one multipart is probably not the best solution. Clustering them into groups is going to work better than one massive shape.

The reason for converting into one is that next I want to intersect with a grid, to compute the amount of forest per grid cell. What would be a better format than shapefile, here?

Intersect with the grid first (provided, of course, that "grid" means a "rectangular tessellation in vector space"; if you mean "raster" then make a tessellation that aligns with the raster, then do that first). For most purposes, CSV is a better format than shapefile, as is every other format.
